# accessing a hbs variable through script file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, hbs

I made a hbs page(dashboard) which is rendered by app.js and has a 'user' name variable passed at time of rendering `//res.render('dashboard',{user:user})`.I can easily use the variable in the hbs file using for each loop and successfully display its content ,but when I try to access the variable through the script file it says undefined in the developer console when I pass it in console.log. Please help me with the helper like json I tried it but gives error.

dashboard.hbs :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     {{>navbar name=name logout=logout}}
  <style>
    *{
      font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    h1{
      position: relative;
      top:20px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
</style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add task...">
        <button type="submit" id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
 <div class="container">
 <div id="left" class="faded"><h1> Tasks <img src="task.png" width="50" height="45"></h1>
 {{#each user.dashboard}}
 <div class="list" draggable="true"><img class="bulletin" src="bulletin.png"/>{{this.tasks}}<img class="delete" id="delete" src="delete.png"/></div>{{/each}}
 </div>
 
 <div id="middle" class="faded"><h1>In Progress <img src="progress.png" width="50" height="45"></h1></div>
 <div id="right" class="faded"><h1>Completed <img src="completed.png" width="50" height="45"></h1></div>
 </div>

 <script> var user =`{{ user}}`;</script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

script.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    console.log(user.username);


  $("#add").on("click", function () {
      if ($("#input").val() != '') {
          var div = $("<div>").addClass("list").attr("draggable", true);

          var img = $('<img />', {
              class: 'bulletin',
              src: 'bulletin.png',
          });

          div.append(img);
          div.append($("#input").val());

          var del = $('<img />', {
              class: 'delete',
              src: 'delete.png',
              id: 'delete',
          });

          div.append(del);
          $("#left").append(div);
          dragAndDrop();
      }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
      $(this).closest('div').remove();
  });

  dragAndDrop();

  function dragAndDrop() {
      $(".list").on("dragstart", function (e) {
          let selected = $(this);

          $("#left, #middle, #right").on("dragover", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
          });

          $("#left, #middle, #right").on("drop", function (e) {
              $(this).append(selected);
              selected = null;
          });
      });
  }
});
```

[user.username undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVe06.png)

user schema:

```
{
    username: {  
        type:String,
        required: true
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            unique:true
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            unique:true
        },
        confirmpassword:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            unique:true
        },
        phone:{
            type:Number,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        age:{
            type:Number,
            required:true,
        },
        tokens:[{
            token:{
                type: String,
                required:true,
            }
        }],
        dashboard:[{
            tasks:{
                type:String,
                default: 0
            },
          
        }]

   
}
```

sorry for the over details if i did

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars is run on the server, while the script is run in the browser - that's one of the reasons why you cannot access the `user` variable from your script.

One possibility is to serialize your variable inside a script tag.

First you have to register a helper, like:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

```
<script type="application/json" data-json="user">
{{{ json user }}}
</script>
```

Now in your script file:

```js
const user = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('[data-json="user"]'));
console.log(user); // it will have your user info
```

Remember to strip down sensitive information like the `password` (that shouldn't be unique by the way, and not stored as plain text!).

Comment: I added the hbs helper in the server file and others in their mentioned file but nothing happened , although the tasks was to fetch the info of user from database and display in handlebars , which I now achieved by passing the user object directly to hbs and filtering the content and displaying as per need . Thanks for the consideration.